# Trying to input in last pointer of array index used

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, multidimensional-array, c-strings

I am trying to input names and save them in a pointer. then to add more customers starting in the last index I left off in the input before. but I cannot get it right. any tips?
sorry for putting all of the code it is just for understanding better.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #define SIZE 50
    
    int main(){
    int x;
    char name[SIZE][SIZE];
    char *namePtr[SIZE][SIZE];
    
    printf("enter no of customers ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    
    puts("enter customer names");
    
    for(size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < x; ++i, ++j){
        scanf("%s", &name[i][j]);
        namePtr[i][j] = &name[i][j];
        }
        
        puts("\nPrinting using pointer\n");
        
        for(size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < x; ++i, ++j){
            printf("%s ", &*namePtr[i][j]);
        }
        puts("\n");
        
        int c;
        printf("2nd number of customers to add ");
        scanf("%d", &c);
        
        puts("enter customer names");
        
        for(size_t i = x , j = 0; i < c+x; ++i, ++j){
            scanf("%s", &*namePtr[i][j]);
        }
        puts("printing customers combined\n");
        
        for(size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < x+c; ++i, ++j){
            printf("%s ", &*namePtr[i][j]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The results are
Ali Mike Will (NULL) (NULL)

keeping in mind the first amount of customers is 3
the second is 2

Comment: Tips `&*` is never a good idea

Comment: without them, i get a warning and the program crash

Comment: i just removed them and its still not working

Comment: Maybe you want `char *namePtr[SIZE];` ?

Comment: I think you need to take a look to `char`, `char*` and `char[]` to handle one string. Then try to do array of strings.

Comment: no luck. I'm trying to make the first index of rows as the names of the customers and in columns to add more data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration

```
char *namePtr[SIZE][SIZE];
```

does not make a sense.

You need to declare SIZE pointers to strings like

```
char *namePtr[SIZE];
```

As a result of the invalid declaration the following for loops also do not make a sens.

Moreover this for loop

```
for(size_t i = x , j = 0; i < c+x; ++i, ++j){
    scanf("%s", &*namePtr[i][j]);
}
```

invokes undefined behavior because pointers in the array `namePtr` with indices starting from x are not initialized.

It seems what you need is something like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 50

int main( void ) 
{
    char name[SIZE][SIZE];
    char * namePtr[SIZE];
    
    printf("enter no of customers ");

    int n = 0;
    scanf( "%d", &n );
    
    printf( "enter %d customer names\n", n );
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        scanf( "%49s", name[i] );
        namePtr[i] = name[i];
    }
    
    puts( "\nPrinting using pointer" );
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s ", namePtr[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    printf( "\n2nd number of customers to add " );

    int m = 0;
    scanf( "%d", &m );
    
    printf( "enter %d customer names\n", m );

    for ( int i = n; i < m + n; i++ )
    {
        namePtr[i] = name[i];
        scanf( "%49s", namePtr[i] );
    }
    
    puts( "\nprinting customers combined" );
        
    for ( int i = 0; i < n + m; ++i )
    {
        printf( "%s ", namePtr[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Try to run the program.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understood the logic behind why wasn't the code executing properly. the program ran great and thanks again

Comment: quick question can I make the same steps but with a pointer to int array?

Comment: @fvaisal Yes, you can.